# In the inception neural network, how is an image of shape $224 \times 224 \times 3$ converted into one of shape $112 \times 112 \times 64$?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, pooling, convolution-arithmetic, inception

According to the [original paper](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Szegedy_Going_Deeper_With_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf) on page 4, $224 \times 224 \times 3$ image is reduced to $112 \times 112 \times 64$ using a filter $7 \times 7$ and stride $2$ after convolution.

- $n \times n = 224 \times 224$
- $f \times f = 7 \times 7$
- stride: $s = 2$
- padding: $p = 0$

The output of the convolution is $(((n+2p-f)/s)+1)$ (according to [this](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)), so we have $(n+2p-f)=(224+0-7)=217$, then we divide by the stride, i.e. $217/2=108.5$ (taking the lower value), then we add 1, i.e. $118+1=119$.

How do we get an output image of $112$ now?

Answer (score 1):

The padding is not size zero* in the inception CNN layers. In fact it is deliberately chosen to pad so that the convolution by itself would produce an image the same size as the original. I.e. $p=(f−1)/2$, in some libraries this is called "same" padding.

So, $p=3$

The stride is not 2. It is $s=1$ for the convolution. The Inception CNN does not use strided convolutions. Instead the stride of 2 is associated with a later max-pooling layer.

Therefore, using $(((n+2p-f)/s)+1)$ with the correct values $(((224 + 6 - 7)/1)+1 = 224$

Then apply max-pooling, with stride 2. $224/2 = 112$.

---

* Not to be confused with "zero padding" which means pad using $0$ as the value to insert into the new area. So you can have "zero padding with $p=3$"

Comment: thank you for your opinion. Even with `p`=`1` which is obviously isn't the case.  Still doesn't explain `112x112`

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth: 112 is just half 224 . . . easy to explain after using "same" padding. Stride is 1 for convolution, the stride of 2 is a max pooling layer, it is not a strided convolution done in one step. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @santhosh: what Neil presents here is not an opinion. It is a fact-based answer to your question. The important difference to an opinion is that fact-based answers can be correct or wrong. In contrast to opinions. Opinions are inherently vague and subject to discussion and cannot be right or wrong.